# Nav bar won't center

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of new to programming and can't seem to figure out why my nav bar has changed from being centered to floating to the left. I have tried to play around with the code in many different ways and can't figure out why it isn't centered. Below is my css code:

```css
nav  {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: .5em;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: none;    
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset; 

}

nav li {
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    float:left;
    padding: .8em 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    font: bold 1.1em/1 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff #ccc #999 #eee;
    background: #c1c1c1;
    background: linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);       
}
 
nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background: #b40000;
    background: linear-gradient(#ef0000, #b20000);
}

nav a:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
}
 
nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;            
}

nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0px 0px 0;            
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>               
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your snippet has the navbar centered?

Comment: it is centered for me

Comment: It's centered. What's the issue please? you mean on smaller viewports it gets floated to the left?

Comment: What browser do you use? In chrome it is centered.

Comment: This is the actual website that the nav bar has been used in: www.tekmillion.com

Comment: i can see it as centered chrome 43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you css file `NAV` is added extra before `nav` attribute. Remove `NAV` from stylesheat

```
NAV nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

it should be like this

```
nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't saw that extra "NAV" where was it?confused :/

Comment: It is in your css file

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

added padding to left,you can try padding to all over your nav bar to position

```
nav  {
          padding-left:100px;//MODIFICATION and CAN BE CHANGED TO "padding:"
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```